# How to show a character n times in XSLT?

Tags: xslt

I have a template with a parameter. How can I insert a tab character n times?

n is the value of the parameter.

Comment: @Alejandro I think you should have commented on the answer, or add your own answer if you thought the accepted answer was too wrong. You edited the content provided by another user, and that is only encouraged to improve readability or add info.

Comment: Do note that accepted answer is wrong.

Comment: @Alejandro You may ask in http://meta.stackoverflow.com/ to clarify any doubts. Un abrazo!

Comment: @belisarius: From [this meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24322/what-should-be-done-with-accepted-yet-wrong-answers/24326#24326), it looks like editing is not ill-advised (even by [Jeff Atwood](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24322/what-should-be-done-with-accepted-yet-wrong-answers/24323#24323) if it's really a wrong answer.)

Comment: @Flynn Understood. Previous comment deleted. Sorry.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just call it recursively; output a tab, then call the same template again with n-1 passed in, if n > 1.

```
<xsl:template name="repeat">
  <xsl:param name="output" />
  <xsl:param name="count" />
  <xsl:if test="$count &gt; 0">
    <xsl:value-of select="$output" />
    <xsl:call-template name="repeat">
      <xsl:with-param name="output" select="$output" />
      <xsl:with-param name="count" select="$count - 1" />
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

As has been pointed out, this example will actually output a minimum of one. In my experience where the output is whitespace, it's usually needed. You can adapt the principle of a recursive template like this any way you see fit.

Comment: @Alejandro: Ah, that makes more sense;  the test should be `&gt; 1`, not 0. You didn't bother to explain why it was wrong before. It's SUPPOSED to output at least one, as whenever you want to insert X whitespace, in 99% of cases you must insert at least one, hence the `<xsl:value-of` prior to the `<xsl:if` is quite correct.

Comment: From my [revision](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/5089179/revisions)'s title: *"Testing for cero iteration first."*

Comment: @Alejandro: That only told me that it would output once even if the input was zero, which didn't make it wrong. Obviously that's not what you meant, but that wasn't well explained.

Answer (score 15):

In XSLT 2.0:

```
<xsl:for-each select="1 to $count">&#x9;</xsl:for-each>
```

(Sadly though, I suspect that if you were using XSLT 2.0 you wouldn't need to ask the question).

Another technique often used with XSLT 1.0 is the hack:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//*[position() &lt;= $count]">&#x9;</xsl:for-each>
```

which works provided the number of elements in your source document is greater than the number of tab characters you want to output.

Comment: +1 For the fixed "you might go to hell if you use this pattern" iteration. Many times, stylesheet have enough nodes so `document('')//node()` is handy.

Answer (score 4):

This seems the simplest and most flexible to me.

For XSLT 1.0 (or perhaps 1.1).

```
<xsl:variable name="count">10</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="repeat"><xsl:text>&#9;</xsl:text></xsl:variable>
<xsl:sequence select="string-join((for $i in 1 to $count return $repeat),'')"/>
```

Of course the **count** variable is where you assign your **n** parameter.

I used the variable **repeat** to hold the **tab** character, but you could just replace the **$repeat** with the tab character in single quotes in the sequence element. **Note:** This variable can be of a length greater than 1, which creates a whole bunch of possibilities.

It does not use recursion, so it won't run into a recursion limit.

I don't know the maximum value you can use for count, but I tested it up to 10,000.

Comment: "*For XSLT 1.0 (or perhaps 1.1).*" No. This requires XSLT 2.0

Answer (score 3):

Globally define a long enough array of tabs:

```
<xsl:variable name="TABS" select="'&#9;&#9;&#9;&#9;&#9;&#9;&#9;&#9;'" />
```

Then use like this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="fn:substring($TABS, 1, fn:number($COUNT))" />
```

Answer (score 2):

(XSLT 1.0)

```
<xsl:template name="tabs">
    <xsl:param name="n"/>

    <xsl:if test="$n > 0">                              <!-- When n = 0, output nothing.           -->
        <xsl:call-template name="tabs">                 <!-- Recursive call: call same template... -->
            <xsl:with-param name="n" select="$n - 1"/>  <!-- ... for writing n - 1 tabs.           -->
        </xsl:call-template>
        <xsl:text>&#x9;</xsl:text>                      <!-- Add one tab character.                -->
    </xsl:if>

</xsl:template>
```

Example usage:

```
<xsl:call-template name="tabs">
   <xsl:with-param name="n" select="3"/>
</xsl:call-template>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've discovered an LGPL-licensed library for doing this called functx, as I was sure someone had to have already done this... This is a "standard library" type XSLT library, which contains a function called repeat-string. From the docs:

> The functx:repeat-string function returns a string consisting of a given number of copies of $stringToRepeat concatenated together.

Where I use it like this in my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:functx="http://www.functx.com">
  <xsl:import href="../buildlib/functx-1.0.xsl"/>

  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

  <xsl:variable name="INDENT" select="'   '" />
    ....
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

      <xsl:template match="data-pusher-properties">
          <xsl:for-each select="property">
              <xsl:choose>
                  ...
                  <xsl:when test="boolean(@value = '${pusher.notifications.server}')">
                      <xsl:value-of select="functx:repeat-string($INDENT, @indent)" />
                      <xsl:text>&quot;</xsl:text>
                      <xsl:value-of select="@name" />
                      <xsl:text>&quot;: </xsl:text>
                      <xsl:text>&quot;</xsl:text>
                      <xsl:value-of select="$pusher.notifications.email.server" />
                      <xsl:text>&quot;\&#xA;</xsl:text>
                  </xsl:when>
                  ...
              </xsl:choose>
          </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

So for printing a tab character n times, call it like this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="functx:repeat-string('&#x9;', n)" />
```

I know this question is old, but I hope this can still help someone.

[Documentation for the repeat-string function](http://www.xsltfunctions.com/xsl/functx_repeat-string.html)