# XSL: Problem with cicling

Tags: xslt

I know that being a functional language, XSL doesn't have something like traditional for loops (but for-each).

I'm trying to create a table with a fixed number of  (7) starting from a variable number of elements. In a word, I have

```
<items>
    <item />
    <item />
    <item />
</item>
```

How can I turn this into

```
<table>
    <tr><item /></tr>
    <tr><item /></tr>
    <tr><item /></tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>
</table>
```

? With `count()` it is easy to calculate that I need 4 more empty , but how to do this? With a for loop I could easily solve the problem, or maybe modifying `<items>` adding 4 empty elements to it, but, being new to xsl, i can't even do that.

Thanks

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for two different non-recursive ways to solve your problem. Non-recursive solutions should be preferred over recursive ones, as explained in my answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to show a character n times in xslt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5089096/how-to-show-a-character-n-times-in-xslt)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for a recursion solution.  The solution involves writing a template that calls itself when a passed in count is less than the number of times you need the template to run.

A good example is posted by IBM at:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-tiploop.html

You're code may look something like:

```
<xsl:template name="itemLoop">

  <xsl:param name="count" select="0"/>

  <xsl:if test="$count &lt; 7">
    <tr><xsl:apply-templates select="/items/item[$count]"/></tr>
    <xsl:call-template name="itemLoop">
      <xsl:with-param name="count" select="$count + 1"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:if>

</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1):

**It is best to always avoid recursion, when possible**.

In XSLT 2.0 one simply writes:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:param name="pNumRows" select="7"/>
    <xsl:variable name="vDoc" select="/"/>

 <xsl:template match="items">
     <table>
       <xsl:for-each select="1 to $pNumRows">
        <tr><xsl:copy-of select="$vDoc/items/item[current()]"/></tr>
       </xsl:for-each>
     </table>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**and when this transformation is applied to the provided XML document:**

```
<items>
    <item />
    <item />
    <item />
</items>
```

**the wanted correct result is produced:**

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <item/>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <item/>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <item/>
   </tr>
   <tr/>
   <tr/>
   <tr/>
   <tr/>
</table>
```

**Very few people know that for a large number of cases one can avoid recursion in XSLT 1.0, too**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:param name="pNumRows" select="7"/>
 <xsl:param name="vDoc" select="/"/>


 <xsl:template match="items">
     <table>
       <xsl:for-each select=
             "(document('')//node())[not(position() > $pNumRows)]">
         <xsl:variable name="vPos" select="position()"/>

         <tr><xsl:copy-of select="$vDoc/items/item[position()=$vPos]"/></tr>
       </xsl:for-each>
   </table>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is called the method of Piez and one can read about it **[here](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/muench.html#d9940e300)**.

**Remember**: Recursion is much slower than simple iteration -- it also tends to crash with stack overflow if the list has considerable length (around 1000 or more) and special programmatic measures are not taken.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at this question here:

[How to count elements in categorys and compare it with other categorys in XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5192267/how-to-count-elements-in-categorys-and-compare-it-with-other-categorys-in-xslt/5194929#5194929)

There is the same problem discussed there (the title doesn't mention this)  and there are many good answers on how to solve this.

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example sheet which does what you want. I work out how many items there are using `count` and then how many empty rows I need to create. I use a for_loop template.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <table>
            <xsl:for-each select="//items/item">
                <tr><item/></tr>
            </xsl:for-each>

            <xsl:variable name="itemCount" as="xs:integer" select="count(//items/item)" />
            <xsl:call-template name="for_loop">
                <xsl:with-param name="i">
                    <xsl:value-of select="0" />
                </xsl:with-param>
                <xsl:with-param name="count">
                    <xsl:value-of select="7-$itemCount" />
                </xsl:with-param>
            </xsl:call-template>

        </table>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="for_loop">
        <xsl:param name="i" />
        <xsl:param name="count" />
        <xsl:if test="$i &lt; $count">
            <tr></tr>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="$i &lt; $count">
            <xsl:call-template name="for_loop">
                <xsl:with-param name="i">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$i + 1" />
                </xsl:with-param>
                <xsl:with-param name="count">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$count" />
                </xsl:with-param>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```