# how to loop x times in xslt 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to loop my template according to user selection but I cant find a way to loop it

xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<movies>
  <cd>
    <title>Batman</title>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>Ironman</title>
  </cd>
</movies>
```

showMovies.php:

```
<?php
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
  header('Content-type: application/xml');
  $countMovie= $_GET['countMovie'];
?>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:variable name="total" select="count(/movies/title)" /> //count total movie
  <html>
  <body>

      <xsl:for-each select="movies/cd">
      <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
      </tr>

      </xsl:for-each>

      <xsl:if test="$total &lt; <?php echo $countMovie; ?>"> //check if total movie less than $countMovie
        No more movie
      </xsl:if>

  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

(If $countMovie=5)

Current result:

```
Batman
Ironman
No more movie
```

Expected result:

```
Batman
Ironman
No more movie
No more movie
No more movie
```

I know I need to use `<xsl:template>` and keep calling the template but I tried several times and still fail to do so. How to do a for loop by using template? Thanks

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5089096/how-to-show-a-character-n-times-in-xslt/3788

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean by "user selection". There is no user interaction in XSLT.

If you want, you can [pass a parameter](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116/#section-Passing-Parameters-to-Templates) to the stylesheet and use it in a recursive named template to generate the required number of rows:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:param name="rows"/>

<xsl:template match="/movies">
    <html>
        <body>
            <table border="1">
                <xsl:call-template name="generate-rows"/>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="generate-rows">
    <xsl:param name="i" select="1"/>
    <xsl:if test="$i &lt;= $rows">
        <xsl:variable name="cd" select="cd[$i]" />
        <tr>
            <td>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="$cd">
                        <xsl:value-of select="$cd/title"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>No more movie</xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <!-- recursive call -->
        <xsl:call-template name="generate-rows">
            <xsl:with-param name="i" select="$i + 1"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If your calling application passes `5` as the `rows` parameter, then the result will be:

```
<html>
   <body>
      <table border="1">
         <tr>
            <td>Batman</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Ironman</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>No more movie</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>No more movie</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>No more movie</td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```