# XSLT: Concatenate a string n times

Tags: xslt-2.0

I want to concatenate a string for n times and set it as variable using XSLT 2.0. The string to be concatenated is `../`, n is available as number in a variable.

I tried:

```xml
<xsl:variable name="count-dirs" select="count(tokenize($target-filepath, '/')) - 1"/>
<xsl:variable name="path" select="''"/>
<xsl:for-each select="1 to $count-dirs"><xsl:variable name="path" select="concat($path, '../')"/></xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to show a character n times in XSLT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5089096/how-to-show-a-character-n-times-in-xslt) If not, [edit] your question and add a [mcve] showing where you're stuck instead of just asking for code to be written for you.

Comment: I've provided an example. I want to set the output as variable again. The goal is to get a path upwards in the folder tree

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Life can be so easy...

```xml
<xsl:variable name="count-dirs" select="count(tokenize($target-filepath, '/')) - 1"/>
<xsl:variable name="path">
    <xsl:for-each select="1 to $count-dirs">../</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If you would allow me to approve my answer as working you could save your bot-lifetime :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you want e.g. `<xsl:variable name="path" select="string-join((1 to $count-dirs)!'../', '')"/>` in XSLT 3 or `<xsl:variable name="path" select="string-join(for $i in 1 to $count-dirs return '../', '')"/>` in XSLT 2.

Comment: Thank you. I cannot try it at the moment, but yeah this should also work. That's what I wanted to do.